# Any alternative for FORMATMESSAGE() in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2019

Is there any alternative for the FORMATMESSAGE() function in SQL?

Here is my scenario. I have a variable of VARCHAR(2000) which takes a string and which is getting formatted by FORMATMESSAGE(). Now the length of the variable is changed to VARCHAR(8000), here I cannot use the FORMATMESSAGE() because this function accepts 2047 characters. If the message contains 2,048 or more characters, only the first 2,044 are displayed.

I'm planning to create a function with similar logic, but curious to know if there is any alternative or any other function that does the similar functionality logic.

Note: I cannot split the variable into many and use it.

Comment: Why do you want such a long error message in the first place?

Comment: Basically, I'm not using this function for an error message. I have the string variable that contains the body of the email. Need to change some values in the email body.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to kludge `FORMATMESSAGE` to do something it's not really designed for. Altering email content really doesn't sound like a task for SQL server in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but that's how the existing design and even I'm surprised. That's why I'm planning to create a function to handle this.